# a web server developed by python, how to transfer a image file, and can show in a web browser?

Tags: python-2.7, webserver, basehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I want to develop a simple web server using python to handle some simple http request. I have learn how to response the request, such as transferring html pages or transferring some other file. When I transfer a image file, a client use a browser to get the file, the url is like below:

```
http://114.212.82.104:8080/1.png
```

I set 'Content-Type = application/x-png'. But the browser directly download the file, and can not display in the browser. Not like the image below

```
https://www.baidu.com/img/bd_logo1.png
```

it can display in the browser. How to display the image in the browser?
Can someone help me?

and i know i can encode the image file into html page to fix it. code like below:

```
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        path = os.getcwd()+ self.path
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            with open(path,'rb') as fileTrans:
                content = fileTrans.read().encode('base64').replace('\n','')
            #self.sendContent(200, content)
            self.send_response(200)
            page = "<p>\"fef\"</p><img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,{0}\"/>"
            contentPage = page.format(content)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(contentPage)))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(contentPage)

        else:
            self.sendContent(404,"file do not exists")
```

But I know there must be another way, i see the source code of URL(https://www.baidu.com/)
it just use

```
<img hidefocus="true" src="//www.baidu.com/img/bd_logo1.png" width="270" height="129"></div><a href="/" id="result_logo" onmousedown="return c({'fm':'tab','tab':'logo'})">
```

different from my page:

```
<p>"fef"</p><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,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......
```

Answer (score 0):

OK，I think I have solved this problem.
Just set the attribute - 'Content-Type' of header as 'image/png' instead of 'application/x-png'.